# Why cant I scroll browser window in a loop in console?

Tags: javascript, loops, dom, scroll, console

I want to scroll down the browser window in a loop in console. I want it so that every time a scroll down (x)px down I stop, do something and then scroll (x)px again and then stop etc. until the page with ends (its a very long one, I want to parse info from it).

But when I started I stumbled upon an issue, that the scrolling function is executed only once, after the loop ends.

```
let i = 0;
scrollDownTillEnd = () => {
  for(i; i<100; i++) {
    window.scrollBy(0, 1000);
  };
scrollDownTillEnd();
```

(it is a simplified example, but the idea should be clear)

I put the code in the console, being on a page I want to scroll, and get then the value of i at the end of the loop and only one scroll down.

Please, explain me, why this piece of code behaves like this and how to make it work, as I mentioned before (in every loop it scrolls a little bit).

Thank you!

Comment: Because scrolling provides re-rendering of the page, and that can't happen before all the script is executed.

Comment: Looks like an infinite loop to me: `0 < 100` part is always true. Perhaps you wanted to make it `for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++)`? And there's a bracket missing.

Comment: `window.scrollBy(0, document.body.clientHeight);`, `window.scrollBy({left: 0, top: document.body.clientHeight, behavior: "smooth"});`

Comment: @walk, yeah, its a typo:)

Comment: @Andreas, yes, document.body.clientHeight also suits for scrolling down, I don't have issues with this part, I don't get the loop part and why cant I get a little scroll down **every** loop, not one at the end of the loop run. You can check, that no scroll down is being executed during loop run, when you put smth in between (some simple alert or smth ilke this). Only at the end.

Comment: `scrollBy` is executed on every round in the loop, but the result is not visible until all the script has been executed. A browser has only a single thread for JS and rendering, and all JS is executed before browser can render the results. The solution is a [timed function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Answer (score 0):

Let me help address a few issues going on here.

1) You have an infinite loop going on because you are not checking that `i` is less than 100 even though you are incrementing it each time. You need to check that `i < 100` so that the loop will eventually end. In your loop, 0 will always be less than 100 so the loop will never end.

2) You have a syntax error in your example because you're not actually closing out the `scrollDownTillEnd` function with a curly brace before calling the function itself.

3) Lastly, as good practice, you need to reset your `i` variable to 0 each time so that we can run this piece of code over and over again. The way you have it set up in your example, since `i` will be equal to 100 at the end of the first run, the loop won't ever run again after that until you reset `i` to 0 again. The easiest way to do this is to just initialize `i` to a value of 0 each time you execute this loop.

Try something like this:

```
scrollDownTillEnd = () => {
    for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        window.scrollBy(0, 1000);
    };
};
scrollDownTillEnd();
```

Comment: _"...that the scrolling function is executed only once, **after the loop ends**"_ + _"it is a simplified example"_ -> should only be a typo...

Comment: I'm sorry for typos, but I tried without these silly mistakes in my code (braces and 0<100), but the thing is -- it doesn't work! As Andreas mentioned, the problem is that _"I put the code in the console, being on a page I want to scroll, and get then the value of i at the end of the loop and only one scroll down."_ and _"...that the scrolling function is executed only once, after the loop ends"_.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval() since for loop will executes only once

```
    function scrollDownTillEnd(countryDropdownList)
    {
      let scrollingInterval = setInterval(function(){
      window.scrollBy(0,1000)
      // write your condition
      if (window.scrollHeight > 10000)
      {
      clearInterval(scrollingInterval)
      }
    },100)
    }
scrollDownTillEnd();
```